# yocto, how to build ffmpeg dev packages

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, yocto

I got a yocto built for imx board. I can build ffmpeg package, but need also to populate headers and libraries in my SDK. Building using `bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk` does not add ffmpeg headers to SDK image.

Didn't have any problems with prervious libraires like modbus, etc.

How to build ffmpeg development packages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "ffmpeg" to you local.conf and compile again.

Comment: I already done it, It does produce .so files of fffmpeg libraries, but headers are missing

Comment: then open ffmpeg.bb file and add at last FILES_${PN} ="${includedir}/*" let me know if its works or not.

Comment: @Siva.V No change, still headers are missing. There were some issueas with installed-vs-skipped so had to add also INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "installed-vs-shipped"
After populating sdk and installing it still only .so files are delivered.

Comment: for workaround you can copy headers files to systoofs of your sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need ffmpeg-dev as well. Headers go to -dev package. In general, you can check the packages that are produced by a recipe using oe-pkgdata-util. In this case:

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p ffmpeg
```

And to find which package a specific file belongs to, say swresample.h:

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util find-path *swresample.h

  ffmpeg-dev: /usr/include/libswresample/swresample.h
```

To understand how to add packages to target toolchain, please see:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-adding-individual-packages

Comment: Thanks it works, but why do I need to add "ffmpeg-dev" to include headers in sdk and for example adding libmodbus does not require it(headers are included in sdk automatically)?